# Upload documents to google drive from Appengine-django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I am new to appengine , and i am using pure django project with appengine ,How can i upload documents to google drive ? Any link / guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Follow step by step [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python). This quickstart will guide you to upload documents to Drive. If you are using App Engine, do not follow step 2 and download [google-api-python-client for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-python-client-gae-1.1.zip&can=2&q=) and unpack it to the root of your project folder. Else than that, everything is same.

Comment: Thanks , But it is giving error for verification code, any idea how to do verification automatically ?

Comment: You need to implement your own authentication application. Here is a sample code with some explanations about authentication with django. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django